# how to set box shadow in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface, figma

I have a figma design and I need to set box shadow like this.

```
Drop shadow
x 0, y : 1, B: 5, S: 0, #000000 30%
```

[image: Drop Shadow]

Answer (score 10):

Use a `Container` widget and set the `boxShadow` property from its `decoration` property.

**Code Sample**

```dart
Container(
  height: 75,
  width: 150,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        offset: Offset(0, 1),
        blurRadius: 5,
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

[Try the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/f8996f249af6fdceaaeda7aecdd4ccdc?null_safety=true)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Container and BoxDecoration

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1, horizontal: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
            offset: Offset(0, 1),
            blurRadius: 5,
            spreadRadius: 0,
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I will check and come back soon. Thank you